# How to use Find expresstion in jquery to find the exact xml node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xml-parsing

I hade a xml string and convert it to xmlDom object in jquery it is something like this :

```
  '<Form>
            <Menu>
                <Title>Hello world1</Title>
                <Val>val0</Val>
            </Menu>
            <Menu>
                <Title>Hello world2</Title>
                <Val>val1</Val>
             </Menu>
       </Form>'
```

I want to have a query that give me title of All Menu tags that have Val=val0,
I wrote this

```
$(xml).find("Form > Menu > Val:eq('val0')") .each(function () { alert($(this).text()); });
```

it gives me just val0 ,but i want to give me 'Hello world1'
how to fix this?

Comment: `eq` in CSS (jQuery) selectors is used for indexing, not for matching text value of the mode. Try `Form > Menu > Val[text='val0']`, but it hardly will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 alert($(this).siblings("Title").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the `<Val>` element, so calling `$(this).text()` will return the text of the `<Val>`. You'll need to access the `<Title>` sibling of `this` (your `<Val>` element), then get the text of that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [:contains(Val0)](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)